# CodeIgniter - I can't update row in my table

Tags: codeigniter

I can't find the correct way update one row in my table.

My view:

```
...
<?php echo form_open('ImenikController/verify_editing_phonebook/'.$this->uri->segment(3)); ?>
Ime i prezime*:
<input type='text' name='ime_prezime' value=""> <br><br>
    Ulica i broj: <input type='text' name='ulica' value="">  <br><br>
    Mesto:        <input type='text' name='mesto' value="">  <br><br>
    Telefon*:     <input type='text' name='telefon' value=""> <br><br>

    <u>Napomena: Polja sa zvezdicom su obavezna.</u> <br /> <br />
    <input background:url('images/login-btn.png') no-repeat; border: none; 
      width='103' height='42' style='margin-left:90px;'  type='submit' value='Izmeni'>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
...
```

My Controller:

```
function verify_editing_phonebook()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin') == 1)
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('ime_prezime', 'Ime i prezime', 'trim|required|xss_clean');               
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefon', 'Telefon', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
            {
                $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
                if (isset($id) and $id > 0)
                {
                    $this->load->model('LoginModel');
                    $this->LoginModel->edit_phonebook($id);

                    redirect(site_url().'ImenikController/', 'refresh');
                }
            }
            else {
                $temp = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $obj['id'] = $temp['id'];
                $data['records'] = $this->LoginModel->get_Username($obj);
                $this->load->view('ErrorEditing', $data);

            }
        }
        else {
            $this->load->view('restricted_admin');
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->load->view('restricted');
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
function edit_phonebook($id)
    {
        $data = array ('ime_prezime' => $this->input->post('ime_prezime'), 
            'ulica' => $this->input->post('ulica'),
            'mesto' => $this->input->post('mesto'),
            'telefon' => $this->input->post('telefon'));

       $this->db->where('id', $id);
     $this->db->update('pregled', $data);        
    }
```

That solution doesn't work. 
I get the url:  localhost/imenik114/ImenikController/verify_editing_phonebook

It is a blank (white) page. And not editing row in table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review my post in response to your question.  Consider an up vote to acknowledge the effort made to look through your code and accept the answer if the comments helped you to fix the problem (either directly or indirectly). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Debugging Strategies**

(1) Have you created all the view files?

(2) Have you tested `edit_phonebook($id)` independently?

(3) What does `redirect(site_url().'ImenikController/', 'refresh');` display? 
    Did you define the index function for `ImenikController`?

(4) What URL did you use when you say 'That solution doesn't work.' ?

(5) If your URL is:  "localhost/imenik114/ImenikController/verify_editing_phonebook"
you did not type in `id` in your 3rd segment

(6) If you are not logged in, do you see the correct `restricted` view?

(7) If you are logged in and NOT admin, do you see the correct `restricted_admin` view?

**Potential Bug**

Looking at this part of your code:

```
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            if (isset($id) and $id > 0)
            {
                $this->load->model('LoginModel');
                $this->LoginModel->edit_phonebook($id);

                redirect(site_url().'ImenikController/', 'refresh');
            }
            // You need to handle the case of $id not set
            else
            {
              // load a view with error page saying $id is missing...
            }
        }
```

if your form validates, and you don't pass in `segment(3)`, your controller will not load a view, therefore, you will get a blank page.

You need to check the case of `$id` not present, see code.

**Code Fix**

One more detail: the statement `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);` will set `$id` either to the `id` number or `FALSE`, therefore, you don't need `isset($id)` in your if statement.  I would write `$id = $this->uri->segment(3,0);` to set the default to `0` instead of `FALSE` to keep the logic a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I solved my problem somehow.
I made a link in my view:

Comment: I am glad to hear that you found a solution.  I would appreciate an up vote on my answer, I did take the time to go through your code and I did identify the original cause of your problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer but I solved my problem somehow.
I made a link in my view:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(). 'Controller/edit/'.$row->id; ?>" title="">Edit</a>
```

And in view for editing:

```
<?php echo form_open('Controller/verify_editing_phonebook/'.$this->uri->segment(3)); ?>
```

Function verify_editing_phonebook passed trough validation and loading view.

Thanks once again and sorry for my English...